# SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays() returns 1 when I have 2 monitors

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl-2, multiple-monitors

Good evening.

I'm setting up my game project on a remote computer and am running into a problem with SDL.  I'm using SDL 2.0 and I'm trying to figure out why SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays() returns 1 when I have 2 monitors hooked up to my PC.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and both monitors appear to be configured correctly just using the desktop as normal.

Would appreciate tips on where to look to troubleshoot this issue.  Thanks.

---

**Update 1** - *`./configure` for SDL2-2.0.4 source code*:

Was looking for some mention of X11 in the configure script and saw the following:

```
checking for X11/extensions/Xext.h... yes
-- dynamic libX11 -> libX11.so.6
-- dynamic libX11ext -> libXext.so.6
checking for const parameter to XextAddDisplay... yes
checking for XGenericEvent... yes
checking for XkbKeycodeToKeysym in -lX11... yes
checking for X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h... no
checking for X11/extensions/Xdbe.h... yes
checking for X11/extensions/Xinerama.h... no
checking for X11/extensions/XInput2.h... no
checking for X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h... no
checking for X11/extensions/shape.h... yes
checking for X11/extensions/xf86vmode.h... yes
```

and

```
X11 libraries   : xdbe xshape xvidmode
```

My `xrandr --version` is:

```
xrandr program version       1.4.1
Server reports RandR version 1.4
```

`xrandr --listactivemonitors` doesn't seem to be supported on my install.

---

**Update 2** - *Reinstalled OS, completely wiping partition*:

Things escalated quickly today when I decided just to take the nuclear option.  Fortunately there was nothing on the disk I needed as I had freshly cloned my repo and hadn't made any changes worth committing.

After a day swapping between open and proprietary drivers and tinkering with my xorg.conf, I ended up nuking the disk and installing 16.04 LTS.  I installed the SDL2 runtimes from the ubuntu repo, and I installed the SDL2 development source from the tar file on the SDL website.  Ran my program again and it worked as expected.

I don't want to call this "solved" as I ended up nuking my OS, but I guess my problem is solved.  I just wish I could figure out the information chain on how SDL is informed on how many displays there are.

Comment: Okay, what you want is in`<X11/extensions/Xrandr.h>`, call `XRRGetMonitors` ... now, does SDL have that anywhere? I see a bunch of *other* XRandR calls but not that one ...

Comment: Hm, but SDL *does* call `XRRGetScreenResources` which contains info on "Output"s, which might be what you want ... Note that SDL prepends *all* symbols with `X11_` because of `dlopen` trickery.

Comment: ... except that that would call `SDL_AddVideoDisplay` and affect the return value of `SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays` which was what you asked in the first place. So, how did you get a compiled copy of SDL? If you compiled it yourself, perhaps you were missing some headers?

Comment: Yeah I compiled from source.  I'll check what's currently printing out when I do ./configure for SDL2 and see if I can find a clue there.

Comment: Also sanity-check `xrandr --listactivemonitors` and `xrandr --version` (PS delete some obsolete comments)

Comment: I ended up completely wiping out my OS and installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  `SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays()` now correctly reports 2 displays now.  I kind of wish I knew where the old problem was, but I no longer have it.  I'm pretty sure it was in my `/etc` somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `checking for X11/extensions/Xinerama.h... no`

That's probably what torpedoed you.  [Xinerama is used to query the output count/positions/topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama#Use_in_non-XINERAMA_environments):

> The X server's client/server architecture allows the server to expose Xinerama information to the client regardless of whether the Xinerama infrastructure is active. RandR and NVidia's twinview utilize this feature to provide window managers and clients with information about the output layout relative to the framebuffer.

Installing `libxinerama-dev` & re-`configure`ing probably would have cleared that up.

Comment: I'm glad you posted this.  I had done some more installing after the OS install, mostly related to getting steam and a low-fi game up and running to verify my system settings, and at some point the problem was reintroduced into my system.

I installed the dev package, `./configure`d, built and installed and now it works like expected.  Thanks for your insight.

Also, Xrandr was also mentioned in the ./configure script when I ran it just now, so technically I'm not sure if it was the presence of the Xinerama or Xrandr dev packages which I also installed yesterday while troubleshooting

Comment: [`xrandr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR) *mostly* handles video mode changes & management, if your app(s) never change the resolution/refresh rate you probably would be OK.  Good to have though.  You'll also probably want the XInput2 dev libs, that'll give you proper mouse capture and/or relative mouse input.

Comment: @Teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeej: Though honestly 16.04's repo-provided `libsdl2-dev` would probably be fine, no real need to build from source unless you're running into post-2.0.4 bugs that have been fixed in hg.

Comment: The compiling from source is more for my software development process and personal education, helping me understand what's connected/linked and what's not in my system and in linux in general.  I want at least one unchanging source of SDL2 2.0.4 so even if ubuntu upgrades its dev package I'll still have the version upon which my program depends.

I think when I have a moment I'm going to try a fresh OS and SDL2 source install with just the libxrandr-dev and see if I can reproduce the correct results.